# How to avoid repeatedly cloning a 3rd party git repo in CI builds

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have started using AWS CodeBuild to build our projects stored in AWS CodeCommit.
Our project relies on several third party libraries, mostly retrieved as Git, some as HTTP.
Our build script clones/downloads&extracts the required libraries (in the same way we do on our dev systems for local builds). My concern is if we are doing multiple commits a day CodeBuild is repeatedly cloning/downloading from third parties. It seems wasteful, I'm not concerned about our costs/bandwidth, but as more people rely on those third party libraries, their bandwidth/costs would increase significantly. I'd like to avoid that.

1. Is this a concern, or am I being too cautious?
2. what methods are available to me to avoid repeatedly pulling 3rd party libraries?

We are currently not using git submodules, but I don't think that would change anything.

I could use `git clone --depth 1 --shallow-submodules` to reduce the load on 3rd party repositories.

My best solution is to package up 3rd party libraries at the end of every build, store them on S3, and fetch that next build, extract it, and just perform a git pull to check for updates.

A cleaner, though less elegant solution would be to have a separate build system that updates local copies of those libraries to be used by our projects build, this avoids the possibility of any contamination of those 3rd party packages from our build process.

Any simpler options?

Comment: A separate build system that pre-builds/caches copies of your dependencies can actually be better for you in the long run. You can (1) block a given dependency from updating (if the latest version is broken), (2) build your your copies even if the third-party repo is offline, and (3) it gives you a good audit trail if you ever have to determine exactly which commit of a dependency you built against (e.g., in the case of a licensing change.)

Answer (score 1):

> I could use `git clone --depth 1 --shallow-submodules` to reduce the load on 3rd party repositories.

You can also use git sub-module and grab only the latest commit of the submodule
same as you will use in git clone since submodule is doing a git clne once updated.

> There is the `--depth` flag which can be passed to the submodule.
>   The `--depth`flag can be used in the same way as you use it when cloning repository and you wish to clone only the latest commit.
>
> Add the `--depth` option to the add and update commands of `git submodule`, which is then passed on to the clone command.
>   This is useful when the submodule(s) are huge and you're not really interested in anything but the latest commit.

```
git submodule add --depth 1 -- <url>
git submodule update --depth -- <url>
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/275cd184d52b5b81cb89e4ec33e540fb2ae61c1f).